# Is it possible to make topological sorting of regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, search

I made a small search engine and I have regular expression based search. I need to make [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of regular expressions.
A small example what I want as result.

If I use substring search I can search "abc", "bc", "bcd" and "abcd".
"bc" is the most generic string and it returns all results for "abc", "bcd" and "abcd".
"abc" and "bcd" are more generic than "abcd".
But "abc" and "bcd" are not comparable to each other.

Simple case:

```
var bcRegex = /bc/;
var abcRegex = /abc/;
var bcdRegex = /bcd/;
var abcdRegex = /abcd/;

function regexComparator(regex1, regex2){...}

regexComparator(bcRegex, abcRegex); // => greater
regexComparator(abcRegex, bcRegex); // => lesser
regexComparator(bcRegex, bcRegex); // => equal
regexComparator(abcRegex, bcdRegex); // => uncomparable
```

Is it possible to make regexComparator for topological sorting in common case for any regular expressions?

Comment: possibly [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)?

Comment: If you have some regexen that won't be comparable, then how can you have a topological sort, i.e. always a definite order?

Comment: Regular expressions /\d/ and /[0-9]/ are equal but in Levenshtein distance terms it is not.

Comment: In strict sorting we always have the same result after sorting like [1,2,3]. In topological sorting uncomparable items can be in any order. In my example there are two possible answers: [bc, abc, bcd, abcd] and [bc, bcd, abc, abcd].

Comment: Would it be possible to sort by minimum match length?

Comment: Laurel, provide some example please.